# How to set the json response in to dropdown in magento 2

Tags: requirejs, magento2.2.2, json, drop-downs

I got a json response for a dropdown field from  a controller, But how to I append the options to the dropdown, Please provide me a solution. I got response like below.

```
{"content":[{"value":"210","label":"xxx"},{"value":"340","label":"yyy"},{"value":"211","label":"zzz"}]}
```

My Jquery code

```
 success: function (response){
   alert(response[content]);
   }
```

**How do I loop the values and update in the dropdown** Please provide me a solution

**For Reference**

I am trying to convert the below prototype js code to jquery code

```
onSuccess: function (response) {
                let options = response.responseText.evalJSON();
                let opt = "<option value=''>-- Please select --</option>";
                options.each(function (option) {
                    opt += "<option value='" + option.value + "'>" + option.label + "</option>";
                });
                document.getElementById("option_id").innerHTML = opt;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "your-url"
}).done(function(response) {

    jQuery("#your-select-id").append('<option value="">--Please select--</option>');

    jQuery.each(response,function(key,value) {
        jQuery("#your-select-id").append('<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.label+'</option>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This, This will work**

```
 success: function (response){
    var content = JSON.parse(response).content;
    var optionHtml;
    for(var val of content){
      optionHtml +='<option value="'+val.value+'">'+val.label+'</option>';
    }
    $('#your-select-id').html(optionHtml);
 }
```